# Get PFObject another PFObject points to?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

My current user in Parse (on iOS) comes back fine and one of the properties it has is a pointer to a PFObject "A". So when I get the current user I can see a valid pointer in current user to "A".

I can't figure out how to get the actual A object from there.

Ho do I get the actual "A" PFObject if my current user returns a valid pointer to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call fetch, fetchifneeded or another fetch command on "A". http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeeded